# Blob insert in Mysql with PHP script from android

Tags: php, android, mysql, http-post, blob

I have problem to insert image in mysql I get the error

Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '�' at line 26( the line of the Photo).
I already check the convert from byte[] to string is well and reverse to

here is my code :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0,         outputStream);
        photoDB = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

pass it throw intent

```
 String photo =    Base64.encodeToString(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("photo"), Base64.DEFAULT);
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", photo));
```

then Httppost

```
 httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
```

and then PHP script

```
$photo = $_POST['photo'];
$photo1=base64_decode($photo);

$result = mysql_query("insert into table(..,..,..,Photo)values(..,..,..,'{$photo1}')");
```

[image: tuples in mysql table]

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: could you please be more precise how I get hte info from android
still $_POST ?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Fixing that will fix your above problem.

Comment: Ok but why it's working when I'm insert ( TEXT and INT value ) but not when it's blob ?